# No response from recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, palindrome

I want to create a function that is able to determine if a number is same or palindrome. if a given number is palindrome or same then return 2 otherwise if it is not palindrome or same then i need check it twice by increment the given number by 1. after that if it palindrome or same then return 1. if no palindrome or same number found then return 0. i write the function which is giving me the exact result when i give the number as 11211 but the function don't show any response if i enter 1122 or other random value. please help me to find where the error of my function.

```js
function sameOrPalindrome(num) {
  var c = 0;
  var al = 0;
  var normalArray = num.toString().split("");
  var revArray = num.toString().split("").reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < normalArray.length; i++) {
    if (normalArray[i] != revArray[i]) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  if (c == 0) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    num++;
    al = sameOrPalindrome(num);
    if (al == 2) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      num++;
      al = sameOrPalindrome(num);
      if (al == 2) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log("1233",sameOrPalindrome(1233))
```

Comment: what is a *same* number? please add some use cases and the wanted results.

Comment: It likely loops forever

Comment: same number means if i give 1111 the function should return 2

Comment: So the same means one digit repeated a number of times - so `111` `4444` and `66666` are "same" but not `1221`?

Comment: 1221 is a palindrome number if i enter this number the function should return 2

Comment: number having all same digits is itself a palindrome...why the same condition again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution to this problem:

```js
function reversedNum(num) {
    return (
    parseFloat(
      num
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .reverse()
        .join('')
      ) * Math.sign(num)
      )                 
     }
    


      function sameOrPalindrome(num) {
        if (num === reversedNum(num)) {
          return 2;
        } else {
          num++;
          if (num === reversedNum(num)) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            num++;
            if (num === reversedNum(num)) {
              return 1;
            }
          }
        }
        return 0;
      }

      console.log("1233",sameOrPalindrome(1233))
```

Comment: What did you fix?

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with my code?. please give a reply.

Comment: @riyad303030 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61302463/7916438 for that.

Comment: @riyad303030 You have make a recursive function which is not suitable to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not using recurse - I think your function loops

```js
const allEqual = arr => arr.every( v => v === arr[0] )
const sameOrPalin = num => {
  const str = String(num);
  let arr = str.split("")
  if (allEqual(arr)) return 2
  arr.reverse();
  if (arr.join("") === str) return 1;
  return 0
};
console.log("1111",sameOrPalin(1111));
console.log("2111",sameOrPalin(2111));
console.log("2112",sameOrPalin(2112));
console.log("1234",sameOrPalin(1234));

for (let i = 2111; i<=2113; i++) console.log(i,sameOrPalin(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: I assumed if palindrome test is true at first time then return 2. if not try incrementing by one and test the palindrome again . if true return 1 else try incrementing for last time and check the palindrome if true return 1 else 0.

Store string into array first and do `arr.reverse().join("")` to compare

```
  let arr=num.toString().split("");
  if(num.toString() == arr.reverse().join(""))
```

```js
function sameOrPalindrome(num, times) {
  let arr = num.toString().split("");
  if (num.toString() == arr.reverse().join("")) {
    if (times == 3) return 2
    else return 1;
  } else if (times > 0) {
    num++; times--;
    return sameOrPalindrome(num, times);
  } else return 0
}
console.log(sameOrPalindrome(123321, 3));
console.log(sameOrPalindrome(223321, 3));
console.log(sameOrPalindrome(323321, 3));
```

Comment: confused about the same number thing..if you  add some point to it ill add it to the solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check_palindrom(num){
    var c1 = 0;
    var normalArray = num.toString().split("");
    var revArray = num.toString().split("").reverse();
    for (var i = 0; i < normalArray.length; i++) {
        if (normalArray[i] == revArray[i]) {
            c1++;
        }
    }
    if(c1==0){
      return 2;
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
}//check_palindrom

function my_fun_check_palindrome(mynum){
    //console.log(mynum);
    var num = mynum;
    var c2 = 0;
    var al = 0;
    var normalArray = mynum.toString().split("");
    var revArray = mynum.toString().split("").reverse();
    for (var j = 0; j < normalArray.length; j++) {
        if (normalArray[j] == revArray[j]) {
            c2++;
        }
    }
    if(c2==0){
      console.log('Number is palindrome. Return Value :'+ 2);
    }
    if(1){
      console.log('checking again with incremeting value my one');
      num = parseInt(num)+1;
      al = check_palindrom(num);
      if(al==2){
        console.log('Number is palindrome. Return Value :'+ 1);
      }else{
        console.log('Number is not palindrome. Return Value :'+ 0);
      }
    }
    
    
}//my_fun_check_palindrome

console.log(my_fun_check_palindrome(1122));
console.log(my_fun_check_palindrome(11221));
```

Comment: my_fun_check_palindrome(124546)
return 2
its return 2 but in this case it should return 0

Comment: I edited the code. Now I am getting same result as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to know if it should not call itself any more, e.g. when it's doing the second and third checks:

```js
function sameOrPalindrome(num,stop) {      // <-- added "stop"
  var c = 0;
  var al = 0;
  var normalArray = num.toString().split("");
  var revArray = num.toString().split("").reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < normalArray.length; i++) {
    if (normalArray[i] != revArray[i]) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  if (c == 0) {
    return 2;
  } else if(!stop) {                       // <-- check of "stop"
    num++;
    al = sameOrPalindrome(num,true);       // <-- passing true here
    if (al == 2) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      num++;
      al = sameOrPalindrome(num,true);     // <-- and also here
      if (al == 2) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

for(let i=8225;i<8230;i++)
  console.log(i,sameOrPalindrome(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We should always strive to make function more effiecient... you dont need to run full loop. plus actual checking of palindrome can me modularized




    function isSameOrPalindrome(num) {
      var normalArray = num.toString().split("");
      var revArray = num.toString().split("").reverse(),
      i;
      for (i = 0; i < normalArray.length / 2; i++) {
        if (normalArray[i] !== revArray[i]) {
         break;
        }
      }
      if (i >= normalArray.length/2) {
        return "Palindrome";
      } else {
        return "Not Palindrome";
      }
    }
function doCheck(num) {
 var isPalindrome = isSameOrPalindrome(num);
    console.log(isPalindrome);
    if(isPalindrome === "Palindrome") {
       return 2;
      } else {
       num++;
        isPalindrome = isSameOrPalindrome(num);
        if(isPalindrome === "Palindrome") {
       return 1;
      } else {
       return 0
      }
      }
}
    console.log("100",doCheck(100));
```